# Function to emulate _gaq_push function

Tags: javascript, function, google-analytics

I need to emulate _gaq_push() function to make old onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Action', 'Event', 'EventName']);" execution safe in runtime. Any Ideas how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like a mock? Something like this:

```
var _gaq = {};
_gaq.push = function(){
  console.log(arguments);
}
```